# Question about this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I got the following question:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{q \rightarrow \infty }(a^{q}+b_1^{q}+ \cdots b_n^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}},$$ where $a$ is the biggest of $a,b_1,\cdots b_n$

I think the answer is $a$ but I had problems when solving it. Here is my proof:

$$\lim_{q \rightarrow \infty }(a^q+b_1^q+ \cdots b_n^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}=\lim_{q \rightarrow \infty }a[1+(b_1/a)^q+ \cdots (b_n/a)^q]^{\frac{1}{q}}.$$ I think the value in the parenthesis is $1$, but I cannot show this clearly. Why?

Comment: Hint: the value in the parenthesis is no bigger than $n+1$.

Comment: If you can show that the expression in the brackets is *bounded*, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

By the hint of  Aby Coathin, I got
$$a \leq a(1+ (b_1/a)^{q}+ \cdots)^{1/q} \leq a(1+n)^{1/q}$$
so I can use the squeeze rule getting the answer, thank you.